Calculating Offset Values in 010 Editor based on variable inputs
I am currently trying to reverse engineer a certain file with a header (that's already done) and a list of entries.
This is the 010 Editor Template so far:
struct FILE {
    struct HEADER {
        uint32 entryNum;
        // Number of Entries
        uint32 entryFilepathNum;
        uint32 entryListLength;
    } header <bgcolor=0xA4F263>;
    
    struct LIST {
        uint32 offsetPointer;
        // Offset of the Pointer starting after the final List entry
        uint32 offsetMaterial;
        // Offset of the assigned Material starting after last Pointer entry
        } list[file.header.entryNum[0]] <bgcolor=0x8D52CC>;

} file;

My problem now is that I need to calculate the length of both the Pointer and the Material based on its own offset and of the one after that, but this is where I'm stuck.
This is the hex code I'm reverse engineering
